# instagram descriptions throws js error

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I'm using instagram's api to feed some photos into my db and then present them using a javascript map plugin (ammap). The problem is that people post all sorts of weird characters and funky stuff in their phots' descriptions.

In the following description I get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
Walking to the Devils Punchbowl Falls in the rain would have been fun if it hadn't been for all the steps. Hardest kilometre I have ever have to trudge!  In the end this 130m falls was worth all the effort. 
Have a great day. 
#all_my_own #au_nz_hotshotz #capturenz #exploring_the_world_21 #hot_shotz #ig_newzealand #inzed #kiwi #nzmustdo #nature_isa #newzealand #nzroadtrip #natureaddict #ourlonelyplanet #roadtrip #travel #thetravelbible #worldbestgram #fpog #arthurspass #purenewzealand
```

How I'm using the data

1. I get the data from a text field in my db
2. I then use it in the script as follows

   description:"' border='0' style='padding:15px;'/>

   "

now I'm noticing that even in stackoverflow the code doesn't render.

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BrRe9/

here is what I do in php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getData)){
                $retdata[] = array(
                    'desc' =>  $row['desc'],

....
```

Then here is what i do in javascript

```
var dataProvider = {
            map: "worldLow",

            images:[
                <?foreach($retdata as $rr):?>
                {
                    description:"<div style='width:100%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;'><p><?php echo addslashes($rr['desc']);?></p><div>"
                },
                <?  endforeach;?>
              ]                    
            };
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you take a description and try to render it?

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the `'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell PHP to “escape” the description, because it could contain characters that would result in invalid Javascript.

Try this where you insert the description:

```
<?php echo json_encode(addslashes($rr['desc'])); ?>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. It throws a the same error but this time when I click on it, the console is empty and doesn't send me to the problematic text.

Comment: What does it look like in the source?

Comment: it added " at the start and the end of the string, which messed up the whole structure the quotes in that expression.

Answer (score 0):

"If you can get the description returned by the PHP into a variable ('desc'), try this before you do anything with it in javascript:

`var newDesc = desc.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,:]/g, "").replace(/'/g, "\'");`

That should remove most the usual funky suspects and escape the single quote.

Comment: i cannot get it into a variable because I'm running a php foreach in the js array. I might be able to replace the strings in php tho.